# Apache geode failing with OOM exception

Tags: geode

I am trying to create a REST application over Apache geode. Application works well in case of limited data, but in cases when I need to get the complete data ( ~0.8M ), it fails with an OOM exception on server.

Exception :

**HTTP GET Error: 500**

**REST OQL Response: {"cause":"Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space"}**

I tried the same approach with cache client, it works seamlessly, but we need to use REST to integrate with our application.

Any ideas to go around with this? 
I am thinking on the following approaches.

1. Can we break the data on server side and use something like "Range" with Apache Geode? I tried this quickly, but did not work well.
2. Can we start getting the data into smaller buffers at the client side and start reading buffer by buffer?
3. Is it possible to get data out from Geode as a data-stream?

Thanks,

Abhay

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible for your to share the stack trace for the OOM you are getting? Are you saying the results are 0.8 **megabytes**? That doesn't seem like it should cause on OOME.

You can get ranges of data using [OQL queries](https://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/latest/rest_apps/get_execute_adhoc_query.html), but if your data set is really that small it seems like something else strange is going on with the REST API.

Comment: It's not 0.8MB but 0.8 million records. Sure, will send out the stack trace tomo

Comment: Can you please post any example of retrieving ranges for OQL queries, and then iterations over the retrieved keys to fetch the values.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm guessing you are using GET /gemfire-api/v1/region to get all of the values?

The first thing to try would be to get all of the keys and then get the values for gets in batches. For example

```GET /gemfire-api/v1/region/keys```

Break up your keys into batches and for each batch of keys, do something like this:

```GET /gemfire-api/v1/region/key1,key2,...,keyN```

From: https://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/12/rest_apps/develop_rest_apps.html#topic_qhs_f25_m4

Comment: An OQL query for a range of keys would really depend on the type of keys. Are your keys Strings, or something else?

Comment: Thanks Dan. Yes, we are having Strings for now, but do not want to lock us down on Strings. Is there any way I can retrieve keys for an OQL query? Once I get the keys, I can retrieve the data by iterating over those. Did not find this answer in documentation.